# After importing .fbx model to Unity it is possible to go through it

Tags: import, unity-game-engine, blender

I have some models created in makehuman and edited in blender. I export them in fbx and import into unity, but when i put "generate collider" it doen't do anything. I find a solution in adding to a model new collider (capsule for example), but it seems to me that it is really a wrong way to do it

Comment: and i tried to export directly from makehuman, result it the same

Answer (score 0):

When you use Generate Collider you are actually creating a mesh collider.

> When you enable Generate Colliders in the Import Settings, a Mesh
>   collider is automatically added when the mesh is added to the Scene.
>   It will be considered solid as far as the physics system is concerned.

[Colliders information](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Mesh.html).

This means that now you have a collider which takes the form of the mesh and you can either re-add the model to the scene so that it contains this mesh collider or you can add it via the Components tab.

You also need to make sure that your new mesh collider can actually collide against other objects. Check what you need to make collisions happen via this table:
[image]

Also it is important to note that using primitives instead of mesh colliders is often preferable due to its performance advantages. An example below on how to avoid using mesh colliders:

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks for answer, as you said i used primitives, but it fills disturbing that it's still didn't work with create colliders. And when i try not to use this primitives and make it rigid, my model just fall down through the scene

Comment: Look at the table I posted, it explains how to make GameObjects collide by telling you which kind of object collide with others.

Comment: Yes, but for me it's just weird that this check in the import settings doesn't work, cuz i,ve never faced something like that

Comment: I think you are not understanding the purpose of the table. Anyway, my solution works for any .fbx. If you want, edit your question and add more details and screenshots of what you are doing.